# Intellij Idea dependency classes imported but unable to instantiate

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

I am using intellij 2019.1.3.

I have created a simple java project using the "hello world" template, and added an external dependency jar via Project structure -> module -> dependencies.

I am able to import classes from the dependency but instantiation fails at runtime with the error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/def/Classname
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.def.Classname
```

To add more information , i created the jar using :-

```
jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Initially it would feel that it is a problem with the custom jar i built, but i tested out and found same behaviour for any jar from official realeases.

Edit: Adding more information. I ran a `jar tvf jarname.jar` and it lists down all the FQDNs of all the dependency classes.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks like the final jar doesn't include the classes from the dependencies for some reason. If the command line Gradle build has the same problem, the issue is not IntelliJ IDEA specific and this question should not be tagged with the IDE you are using.

Comment: The jar does include the classes. I have done a "jar tvf jarname" and it lists down all classes.

Comment: Please share the jar/project so others can reproduce and investigate it.

Comment: Cannot share project since it is official. But i can provide the steps to do so. I have used a gradle multimodule build. Project A does an "implementation project(:B) , where B contains only model classes. Since A is not a spring boot application, i cannot use spring gradle plugin . So i have used the jar task as stated above. Apart from that since A is a httpclient application, it has them in dependencies block.

Comment: Sorry, it's not helpful. Please recreate the issue with a dummy project and share it.